# Use ajax success return formatted data to populate easyUI form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use backend returned data to populate textboxes in the form. If I replace the "result" var with full raw

```
data(eg.{
  name:'myname',
  email:'mymail@gmail.com',
  subject:'subject',
  message:'message',
  language:'en'
}
```

it works... So it make wonder whether the returned data is not formatted properly or what?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  cache: false, 
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',                  
  url: "<%=path%>/storeRace",
  data:{     
      type:'query', venue:'<%=race.getVenue()%>', date:'<%=race.getDate().toString()%>', race_num:'<%=race.getRaceNum()%>'
  },
  success:function(result){
      if(result=="none"){                       
      }                
      else{
          alert(result);
          $('#raceForm').form('clear');
          $('#raceForm').form('load', result);
      }
  },
  error:function(result){
      $.messager.alert('Error',result,'error'); 
  }                  
});
```

Comment: Have you observed the returned data in an HTTP app like Fiddler or Google DHC?

Comment: in success callback show to us console.log(result)

Comment: I am a newbie to frontend coding, but the "alert" within shows the full data returned, whichi is .{
  name:'myname',
  email:'mymail@gmail.com',
  subject:'subject',
  message:'message',
  language:'en'
}

Comment: @Saintor Ok, so lets take that data you received in your "result" and put it in a for each loop.

Comment: No need for easyUI bound the component. You just wire the data right? I got it work with hard coded data

Comment: @Saintor what is the difference between your hard coded data and the data result retrieved by your AJAX call?

Comment: I got data from println both at servlet and alert box in the front, I just grabbed it replace the "result" in $('#raceForm').form('load', result) line...so i figured the "result" is not recognized as a local string data?